# In Gatsbyjs, how to render markdown images when markdown is coming from a yaml object property?

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image, gatsby-plugin, gatsby-remark-image

I am working with a gatsbyjs app, where I have some .yml files that have following format:

[image]

My goal is to render value of **markdownContent** field as HTML. For that purpose, I first read contents of these .yml files using 'gatsby-transformer-yaml' plugin and then I use **remark** and **remark-html** to convert the value of **markdownContent** field to html.

The html renders just fine, however I couldn't get the image (linked as part of markdownContent field) to render (all image requests return in 404)

Is it even possible this way? If not, how can I get my markdown images to render in HTML when the markdown is not coming from gatsby-markdown-remark?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`gatsby-transformer-yaml-full`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-transformer-yaml-full/#enable-custom-types-with-plugins) which will create a queryable GraphQL node from a YAML input.

Once installed it (by `npm install gatsby-transformer-yaml-full` or its yarn equivalent):

```
// gatsby-config.js

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    'gatsby-transformer-yaml-full',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        path: './content', // Path to your .yaml (or .yml) files
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

This will allow the plugin to create GraphQL nodes, exposed as allCollectionYaml. For example:

```
{
  allCollectionYaml {
    edges {
      node {
        character
        number
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your page/template you just need to access the GraphQL data (stored inside `data` object in the page `props`) and use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to render it:

```
function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.data.allCollectionYaml.edges.node[0].character}} />;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a safer option like [markdown-to-jsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-to-jsx).